# clang not working properly for C++ Exceptions

Tags: clang

```
struct ZeroError{
    int err;
    ZeroError(int e){err = e;}
};


int div(int a,int b)
{
    if (b == 0)throw int(10);
    return a/b;
}


int main()
{
    try{
        int x = div(10,0);
        cout<< x;
    }
    catch(int z){
        cout<<z;
    }

}
```

even though exception is caught when i run the program i am getting

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an
>   unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

Comment: Looks like something compiled with exceptions turned off

Comment: Clang support for exceptions in Win32 is not there, yet. http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00015.html

Comment: How do you turn on c++ exceptions in clang? For instance, in msvc you use '/EHsc'

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling with `-fcxx-exceptions`.

Did a little cleanup on your code, using `div` as a function name collided with one in `stdlib.h`. Also tried to make the error output more distinctive.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

struct ZeroError{
    int err;
    ZeroError(int e){err = e;}
};


int divide(int a,int b)
{
    if (b == 0)throw int(10);
    return a/b;
}


int main()
{
    try{
        int x = divide(10,0);
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    catch(int z){
        cout << "Exception: " << z << endl;
    }
}
```

Compiling with the flag seems to work great:

```
% clang++ -fcxx-exceptions foo.cc
% ./a.out
Exception: 10

% clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```